# How to iterate all the children including those without tags in an DOM element with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to parse a ruby tag like this:

```html
<div id="foo">
  <ruby>
      <rb>気</rb>
      <rp>(</rp>
      <rt>き</rt>
      <rp>)</rp>
  </ruby>
  が
  <ruby>
      <rb>狂</rb>
      <rp>(</rp>
      <rt>くる</rt>
      <rp>)</rp>
  </ruby>
  ってしまう。
</div>
```

The problem is, that I am unable to iterate all the child elements including those without tags. All the functions like:
`document.getElementById("foo").children` and `$("#foo").children()`
return only the two ruby tags without the text in between.

I am trying to get a list like:

- {ruby}
- が
- {ruby}
- ってしまう

Is there a way I can get a list of all the tags and text?

Comment: You need `document.getElementById("foo").childNodes`, not `.children`. `childNodes` gets text nodes in addition to element nodes. Note: you'll likely get a lot of white space along with your desired text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting all nodes inside a tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462894/getting-all-nodes-inside-a-tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Node.childNodes` (See [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes))

```
document.getElementById("foo").childNodes
```

But here is where it can get tricky:

In your HTML, between the `<div>` tag and the `<ruby>` tag, there is whitespaces and a newline. This will be parsed as a `TextNode` here. So `.childNodes` will return 5 nodes:

1. A TextNode for what is between `<div>` and the first `<ruby>` (including a newline and whitespaces).
2. The first `<ruby>` element.
3. A TextNode containing the text between the two `<ruby>` elements (including two newlines and whitespaces)
4. The second `<ruby>` element.
5. A TextNode containing the text between the second `</ ruby>` and `</ div>`. (including a newline and whitespaces)

So, if you only need non-empty TextNode, when there is actually some text:

```
const nodes = [...document.getElementById('foo').childNodes].filter(node => !node.nodeValue || node.nodeValue.trim())
```